# Why is the output of this program shows 0 in this Java program?

Tags: java

Program 1 below displays 0 in the output. I think its because i have return C. 
But why it is not displaying 0 in the second program.

Kindly explain when is the return statement comes to the picture. 
Thanks you for the support.

Program 1:

```
public class Division {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int c=divide(4,0); 
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static int divide(int a, int b) {
        int c = 0;
        try {
            c=a/b;
        } catch (Throwable f) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return c; //Why is the output shows 0. 
        }
    }
}
```

Program 2:
I have just changed int `c=divide(4,2);`

```
public class Division {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int c=divide(4,2);
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static int divide(int a, int b){
        int c = 0;
        try {
            c=a/b;
        } catch (Throwable f) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return c; //Why is the output does not shows 0. 
    }
}
```

Program 3:
why I am getting 0 in this program?

```
public class Division {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int c=divide(4,0); 
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static int divide(int a, int b) {

        try {
        int c=a/b;
            return c; 
        } catch (Throwable f) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        //Why is the output shows 0. 
        return b;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be because you are setting c=a/b. Your return value would be 2.

In the first program you are dividing 4 by 0, which makes c = 0.

In the second program you are dividing 4 by 2, which makes c = 2.

Comment: Can you please explain why I am getting 0 in the third program? I did not initialize c=0

Comment: This would be because you are setting int c = divide(4, 0), where 4 is the value of a and 0 is the value of b. When you return b, it will return 0. c is also 0 because 4 divided by 0 is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple dear in your 1st program there is an exception so the value of variable C will not be changed so it returns as 0 as you initializes it with 0.
In your second program there is no exception and hence C has the result of 4/2 which is 2 so now 2 is returned as value of C.

Comment: Can you please explain why I am getting 0 in the third program? I did not initialize c=0.

Comment: In your third program due to Arithmetic Exception you are getting 0 because when the Exception occurs 0 is returned from the divide method try block into variable c.

Answer (score 0):

**Program 2:**
Your method doesn't return `c=0;` because with this:

```
   c=a/b; // according to your values return 2
```

Assign new value to `c`, in java the variable take the last value assigned to it.

**Program 3:**
You get `0` for two reasons:
First you have an error because  you divide an postive `int > 0` by `zero`.
Second the return b is `zero` because b have input value `zero` from method paramater.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version of you program the divisor of you division is `0`. In mathematical terms a division by 0 is undefined and therefore throws an [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html). The variable `c` does not get assigned a new value and therefore at the end when you return it, it shows still the initial value `0`. For a comparison of dividing by `0` (integer) and `0.0` (double) take a look at [this forum post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/527959/java/java/Arithmetic-Exception-Infinity-dividing).

This is the flow of statements, as they are executed:

```
int c = 0; // initializing with 0
a/b; // division by 0 => ArithmeticException, no assignment
System.out.println("Error"); // println in the catch block
return c; // return initial value
```

In your second program the divisor is `2` hence, no exception.

Comment: Can you please explain why I am getting 0 in the third program? I did not initialize c=0.

Comment: In your third program you run into the same issue with the `ArithmeticException` as in the first program. Therefore you do not return at `return c` but after the catch block with `return b`, which is 0.